# Excel, Average for a specific column within table

Tags: microsoft-excel

Im trying to calculate an average just for one column within a table of values.

It is like this:

```
Hi   Hello  Hey
1  |  2   | 3
1  |  2   | 3
1  |  2   | 3
```

And I'm trying to get the average for one of those columns, but which one depends from another cell that will tell me either Hi, Hello or Hey. Lets say such cell is K5

So I thought something like averageif(A1:C1;"="&K5;A2:C4). With K5 being Hi the formula returned the value 1. But when I changed a value in the Hi collumnn, having then:

```
Hi   Hello  Hey
1  |  2   | 3
7  |  2   | 3
1  |  2   | 3
```

The formula still shows me 1 (should be 3), so it is only taking into consideration the second row.

How could I have it calculate the average of A2:A4 if K5 is Hi, B2:B4 if K5 is Hello or C2:C4 if K5 is Hey?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AverageIf`](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/averageif.php) is not built to evaluate a whole table and return only one column. To achieve your described result, you could use something like

```
=AVERAGE(IF(A1:C1=K5,A2:C4,""))
```

This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you the first 2 ways that came to mind.

```
=average(offset(A2:C2,0,match(K5,A1:C1,0)-1))
```

offset shifts your range, match will find K5 in the cells A1:C1 and return which cell it is (1,2,3) subtract one to make the row correct.

Alternatively if you have the data stored as a table this will find the average of any column with the header name in K5.

```
=average(INDIRECT("Table1["&K5&"]"))
```

Indirect basically lets you use variables to define cell references.

Comment: Make `K5` have a Validation consisting of cells `A1:C1` - you get a drop down list to choose from. Works in both Excel and LibreOffice.

Comment: Both Offset() and Indirect() are volatile. They cause a recalculation of everything any time anything is changed in the workbook. That may cause slowness. Volatile functions should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the table function in Excel to make the desired data as a table
(*Highlight it all and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>*) then you can work out the average by using:

```
=AVERAGE([Hi])
```

Assuming your table header is called `Hi`.

You can use this within a larger function such as

```
=100 - ([@hi]) / ( MAX([hi]) + AVERAGE([hi]) )
```

or more if you want to expand this out further.

The `=([@hi])` would give the current `hi` value for that row. The rest is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: Wasn't using the table function but this is great too. Thank you.